# Parsing an XML string fragment out of document in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to use DOMParser, or XPath to get a XML fragment out of a document. A element with either DOMParser or document.evaluate returns an element with a null nodeValue, how do I get the xml fragment back as a string? Here's the example that I can't get to work in WebKit.

XML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="address1_stateorprovince" />
    <attribute name="new_source" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="new_organization" />
    <attribute name="new_lastcontacted" />
    <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
    <attribute name="address1_city" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="new_conflicting" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="new_csuid" />
    <attribute name="new_contacttype" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Source:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var filterXmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
var test = filterXmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filter")[0];
test.nodeValue; // null!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/NodeValue) is the "value" of the node, which for Element types is meaningless (and rightly `null`). It is not the xml string representation of the node.

For WebKit you can use [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLSerializer) to get the string representation back out:

```
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(test);
xml; // <filter type="and"><condition attribute="new_conflicting" operator="eq" value="1"/></filter>
```

---

**Update** re comment "Is there an easy way to only get the inner xml?":

You could construct a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createDocumentFragment) from the *child* nodes, and serialize just the fragment:

```
var frag = filterXmlDoc.createDocumentFragment();
while(test.firstChild) {
  frag.appendChild(test.firstChild);
}
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(frag);
xml; // <condition attribute="new_conflicting" operator="eq" value="1"/>
```

Note that this will empty out your `test` node after running.

Comment: And here's WebKits unbelievably top-to-bottom documentation on `XMLSerializer`: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/XMLSerializer_idl/Classes/XMLSerializer/index.html

Comment: Lol, a joke I take it? Is there an easy way to only get the inner xml?

Comment: @Boog: I think apple just might be serious. Re inner xml, see my updated answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: that's some great Jedi code! Thanks a million. My naive attempt was a for loop on childNodes but I like yours better, it's cleaner and simpler ;)

Comment: @Boog: the `for` loop isn't so bad, as it will still leave `test` node intact unlike my approach which rips its childNodes out. On the other hand, you'd be doing string collecting and [potentially] multiple calls to `serializeToString`, which is completely unnecessary. Meh.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
test.items(0).nodeValue;
```

getElementsByTagName() returns a NodeList so you must use items() method of that object.

Though ideally you would do:

```
if (test.length)
{
    console.log(test.items(0).nodeValue);
}
else
{
    console.log('Nothing Found');
}
```

Comment: I am already getting the first item returned from getElementsByTagName, nodeValue is null.

Comment: Right you are. Didn't notice that at first.  Though I believe you still may want to use item() instead of the array element reference as the latter may have issues with other browsers.